# Setting up Profile Manager for Yosemite OS X Server on a local network

Tags: ios, mdm

I am trying to test OS X Yosemite Server Profile Manager to enrol users and allow them to download an Enterprise app to their iPads. I want the users to be able to enrol their own devices themselves.

For testing purposes only, I have a system running Yosemite server on our own local network, accessible at *yoserver.local*  (IP address currently 10.0.1.30). I set up Open Directory and Profile Manager using the defaults and a self-signed certificate, and added the app via Profile Manager->Apps.

I used Server Admin to create a Local Network user called *testuser*.  I then assigned the app to that user in Profile Manager.

If I try and access *https:/yoserver.local/mydevices* from an iPad,  I am presented with the login panel - but after signing in with the user’s login and password I just get a completely blank screen. I had hoped at least to see information related to the user profile and have it download to the device.

In the Apple docs I see:

> To use Profile Manager as a mobile device management (MDM) service, OS X Server should have a static Internet network address, and a fully qualified domain name, and it cannot be on an isolated network.

Is this my problem?  If so, can anyone suggest a workaround for testing purposes? If not, what (perhaps) obvious step have I left out?

Answer (score 0):

Try to access your local server via *http* not *https*, in your case the link would be http://yoserver.local/mydevices, seems that self-assigned certificate won't work for secure connection.